# Should I say "American grounds" or "American territory"?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

Which one sounds more natural to you?

> If this message still catches you on American territory, I wish you a
>   safe flight!

or

> If this message still catches you on American grounds, I wish you a
>   safe flight!

Comment: One of the most scary things about flying, in my opinion, are the people who wish you a 'safe flight'! Do you wish your colleagues a safe journey home on the bus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use *American territory*, on the grounds that *American grounds* is not a familiar phrase and *grounds* is frequently used to mean "basis," as I just did.

An even better choice, and the one you may have been thinking of when you suggested *grounds*, is *American soil*.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!! Does that sentence as a whole make sense and is well structured to you?

Comment: Yes, it sounds fine.

Comment: Do Google ngrams (perhaps 'committed on American grounds/territory') endorse your claim?

Comment: The problem with *American territory* is that it seems to be of a wrong register for the OP's purposes: it would normally be used in the contexts in which something of legal significance depends on where one is.

Answer (score 0):

Just say, "I wish you a safe flight."  The receiver of your message is "on any grounds somewhere."  Try it!  It'll work!

Comment: How about: Hope this message still catches you on American soil. Have a safe flight!